# insert image in a 'background-image' from a pipe

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code in my html document:

```
<div *ngFor="let search of this.mySearches; let i = index" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="box">
                    <div class="image img-search-rounded">
                      <img [src]="search.postPath | imagenpost: search.generic_category: search.postImg[0]" alt="image" title="image" id="img-rounded" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left">
                      <h4>{{search.generic_category}}<i class="la la-angle-double-right"></i>{{search.generic_type}}</h4>
                      <p><i class="la la-map-marker"></i>{{search.generic_city}}</p>
                      <p><i class="la la-clock-o"></i> {{search.date | date:'medium'}}</p>
                      <p><i class="la la-circle"></i> Get email notifications</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                      <button type="button" [routerLink]="search.url">View</button>
                      <button type="button" (click)="removeMySearch(search._id)">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

but I get this and not the image:

[image: error image]

How could I render the image?

Comment: The pipe works correctly, I know because I use it in another part of the code.

Comment: create the url in your ts file and then pass the variable just to showcase url in html like

Comment: you have a type code error 'url(' + search.postPath | imagenpost **?** search.generic_category: search.postImg[0] + ')' (a ? not :)

Answer (score -1):

It's not quite clear what you're trying to do. It seems like you are trying to do an OR using a ternary operator, but you are missing the else part.

The condition should be something like

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':person.country === 'UK' ? 'green'
> : 'red' }"></<div>
```

Read more about the example [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/)

Comment: I'm not using conditional, the ':' are used to pass several parameters to a pipe. in this case 'imagenpost' is the name of the pipe and the rest are parameters.